# Service onRebind() not being called

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service that implements following callback methods.

```
public bound = false;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    bound = true;
    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}
@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    bound = false;
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    bound = true;

}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
//super.onDestroy();   

}
```

In my activity, I have following code for three button clicks.

```
if(v.getId() == R.id.bind)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);                
}
else if(v.getId() == R.id.unbind)
{
    unbindService(mConnection);
}
else if (v.getId() == R.id.rebind)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

I first bind, unbind and then invoke rebind. In both bind and rebind cases, `onCreate()` and `onBind()` methods of service are called. `onRebind()` is never called. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow these steps:

1. Start service using startService() method from an activity by clicking 'Start Service' button.
2. Bind service using bindService() method from an activity by clicking 'Bind Service' button.
3. Unbind service using unbindService() method from the activity by clicking 'Unbind Service' button.
4. Again click on 'Bind Service' button and then the activity invokes onRebind() method.

**Example Code:**

MyService.java

```
package com.example.service_lifecycle;

public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I am in on create method.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I am in on start command method. " + mStartMode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I am in on bind method. " + mBinder, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I am in on unbind method. " + mAllowRebind, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I am in on rebind method.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onRebind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I am in on destroy method.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

ServiceLifeCycleActivity.java

```
package com.example.service_lifecycle;



import com.example.androidpractice.R;

public class ServiceLifeCycleActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener{

    private Button btnStartService;
    private Button btnStopService;
    private Button btnBindService;
    private Button btnUnbindService;

    private boolean isServiceBind = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_service_life_cycle);

        btnStartService = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStartService);
        btnStartService.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnStopService = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStopService);
        btnStopService.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnBindService = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBindService);
        btnBindService.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnUnbindService = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUnbindService);
        btnUnbindService.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.service_life_cycle, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnStartService:          
            startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
            break;

        case R.id.btnStopService:
            stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
        break;

        case R.id.btnBindService:
            bindService(new Intent(this, MyService.class), mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            isServiceBind = true;
            break;

        case R.id.btnUnbindService:
            if(isServiceBind){
                if(mServiceConnection != null){
                    unbindService(mServiceConnection);
                }           
                isServiceBind = false;
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Service is not bound.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    // Code to manage Service lifecycle.
        private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {                    
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName comName, IBinder service) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName comName) { 

            }       
        }; 
}

res/layout/activity_service_life_cycle.xml


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStartService"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Start Service" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStopService"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnStartService"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="Stop Service" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBindService"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnStopService"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnStopService"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="Bind Service" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnUnbindService"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnBindService"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Unbind Service" />
```

If you have any further question, let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that the `onRebind()` method is only being called when you bind the service from a same activity where it was previously bound to.

In case you are binding a pre-existing service from an old activity to a new activity, the **`onBind()` method is being called**.

In case your app is switching back and forth between foreground and background (e.g. opening from notification) it'll need the `START_STICKY` option in order to not be reinstantiate the service when `bindService()` is called.

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    Log.i("BLECommunicationService", "STARTED")
    return START_STICKY
}
```

Hope it'll help.